# How to zoom in and use the scroll orbiting with a 1mm object?

Tags: 3d-view, scale

I have a 1mm sphere and can't use zoom or scroll to navigate properly, to be clear, at first it was impossible to *zoom in*, then I change the view port scale to 0.001 and again to 1000, after that I was able to zoom in, but not too close of the object.

The other issue is with the scroll orbiting, when I hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> the movement is really slow and without <kbd>Shift</kbd> too fast, is really hard to control.

I have some objects in a normal size (about 10cm) and need to work with this to scale, when I changed the view port scale to 1mm I couldn't zoom out to use the bigger object.

I'm using Blender 2.81

Comment: There shouldnt be a problem. You can leave the viewport scale at is it on 1. I created 20cm object and 2mm and it is ok to navigate. Use ";" key the one above tabulator and the view menu opens, chose "3" to view selected and it will frame your selection, it will help you to see the object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to zoom into 1mm sphere and to solve it you should select the object you want to zoom into then click <kbd>/</kbd> for *Local View*. This works like a charm, but you have to remember to exit local view again to see other objects in the scene.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/local_view.html